# How do you include an "Add element" button to the element selector modal

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, fieldtypes

In my plugin's field types I am extending the `BaseRelationField`.  How do you activate the "*Add Element*" button that shows in the Element Selector modal when the element is double clicked?